# Equivalent Characterization of Norms "induced" by injective linear Mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

When we have vector spaces $V,W$ over the real or complex numbers, $||\cdot||_W$ as a norm of $W$ and a linear injective mapping $f: V \to W$, we can see with little effort that $||v||^f_V=||f(v)||_W$ defines a norm on $V$.

My question is: Does this special norm have a name? And has anyone an idea when a norm $||\cdot||$ is induced in this way, i.e. there exists $g: V \to W$ linear and injective with $||\cdot||=||\cdot||^g_V$?

Thanks for your interest and thoughts in advance

Edit: $(W,||\cdot||_W)$ can not be choosen

I think I make an example:

Does there exist a linear mapping $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ (or matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{2,2}$)  with
$$ ||\cdot||_1 = ||\cdot||_2 \circ A$$ or $$ ||\cdot||_2 = ||\cdot||_1 \circ A\text{     ?}$$
Do we have equivalent criteria to answer this question (for general vector spaces)?

Comment: Every norm can be defined this way.  If $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $V$, and $I:V\to V$ is the identity map, then $\|\cdot\|=\|\cdot\|^I$.

Comment: My question is, if you can do this without choosing the space $W$, sorry for the confusion

Comment: What do you mean by "without choosing"?

Comment: In my version, I assume a space $W$ that can different von $V$, but to make the construction with the identity map, you need to have / choose $W=V$

Comment: Well if you want an example where $W\neq V$, let $W=V\oplus \mathbb K$, where $\mathbb K$ is the field you're working with, let $\|(v,\lambda)\|_W=\|v\|_V+|\lambda|$, and let $f:V\to W$ be inclusion in the first factor.

Comment: It gives me an idea, what I can do, thank you :)

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).